# How to send an email in multiple chunks?

Tags: php, curl, cron, phpmailer

I'm using the php mail function to send email and it's working fine.

The email body is dynamically generated and the problem is that the email recipient can only receive emails that are 160 characters or less. If the body of the email is longer than 160 characters, then I want to split the body into separate blocks, each less than 160 characters.

I'm using CRON Jobs and curl to automatically send the email.

How can I send each separate email to the same recipient when more than one body is generated? Below `$bodyAll` represents that there is only one email to be sent because the dynamically generated content fits within 160 characters. If the body content is more than 160, then `$bodyAll` would not be sent and `$bodyFirstPart` would be sent to the recipient, then `$bodySecondPart`, etc., until all the separate body texts are sent.

```
$body = $bodyAll;
$body = $bodyFirstPart;
$body = $bodySecondPart;
$body = $bodyThirdPart;
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body</i>";
if(!$mail->send())
```

Comment: You're not using the "plain vanilla php mail function"; you're using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), which isn't the same thing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to check the length inside a while loop trimming it down with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), and send each chunk every loop iteration:

```
<?php

$bodyAll = "
  some really long text that exceeds the 160 character maximum for emails,
  I mean it really just tends to drag on forever and ever and ever and ever and
  ever and ever and ever and ever and ever and ever and ever......
";

$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";

while( !empty($bodyAll) ){

  // check if body too long
  if (strlen($bodyAll) > 160){
    // get the first chunk of 160 chars
    $body = substr($bodyAll,0,160);
    // trim off those from the rest
    $bodyAll = substr($bodyAll,160);
  } else {
    // loop terminating condition
    $body = $bodyAll;
    $bodyAll = "";
  }

  // send each chunk
  $mail->Body = "$body";
  if(!$mail->send())
    // catch send error
}
```

Comment: Excellent, simple and elegant, I didn't realize that I could send mail within a while loop. Thank you so much for helping me get unstuck and get past with this simple solution. And, thanks for your patience and for gently asking for clarification.  I apologize for not realizing the importance of submitting whatever code I am using, even if the code is not working and seems like basic, generic code.

Comment: I just did a little edit - you're always sending to the same recipient, so you only need to call `addAddress` once before the loop, and the Subject is the same for every message so you don't need to set that every time either. Rather than all that arithmetic, you could just `foreach(str_split($bodyAll, 160) as $body) {...`.

Comment: Thank Synchro, nice update, that simplifies the processing.